# ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3 but not 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` in Python 3 when trying to import a package containing an `__init__.py` that imports a variable from one of the package's modules.

My project structure is:

```
project/
  test.py
  package/
    __init__.py
    modu.py
```

`modu.py:`

```
value = 99
```

`__init__.py:`

```
from modu import value
```

`test.py`:

```
import package
print(package.value)  # or 'print package.value' for Python 2
```

When I run `test.py` using Python 2, everything works. But when I run with Python 3, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modu'`. I am running from the `project/` directory.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Python3 expect absolute path for modules:

`__init__.py`:

```
from package.modu import value
```

Works on both versions